# How to call the context menu on a single click in a recycler view?

Tags: android

This is my recycler view adapter class, i want program the context menu on a single click here. The reason i wish for that is so that i can directly extract the information from textfields here use them in the context menu.

```
public class AppAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AppAdapter.AppViewHolder> 
{

    private List<UsageStats> appList;
    public static HashMap<String,Boolean> checkAppList ;
    private static Context context;
    private PackageManager packageManager;


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public AppAdapter(List<UsageStats> appList, Context context) {
        this.appList = appList;
        this.context = context;
        packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        checkAppList = new HashMap<>();
        for(UsageStats us: appList){
                checkAppList.put(us.getPackageName(), false);
        }
        Log.i("Hello", checkAppList+"");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return appList.size();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final AppViewHolder appViewHolder, int i) {
        UsageStats ai = appList.get(i);

        if (ai != null) {
            try {
                appViewHolder.appName.setText(packageManager.getApplicationLabel(packageManager.getApplicationInfo(ai.getPackageName(), 0)));
                appViewHolder.appDomain.setText(dateFromMiliSeconds(ai.getLastTimeUsed()));
                appViewHolder.appIcon.setImageDrawable(packageManager.getApplicationIcon(ai.getPackageName()));
                appViewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        Log.i("Hello", "");
                        if (appViewHolder.checkBox.isChecked()) {
                            appViewHolder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFD4DFFF"));
                        } else {
                            appViewHolder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    //

    //
    //

    public String dateFromMiliSeconds(long mili){

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());

        GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(mili);

        return ("Last Used :: "+sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));

    }

    @Override
    public AppViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.card_row, viewGroup, false);

        return new AppViewHolder(itemView, context);
    }

    //Touch methods

    //touch finishes

    public static class AppViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {
        protected TextView appName;
        protected TextView appDomain;
        protected ImageView appIcon;
        protected CheckBox checkBox;
        protected Context context;
        protected CardView cardView;

        public AppViewHolder(final View vi, final Context context) {
            super(vi);
            appName = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
            appDomain = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.app_paackage);
            appIcon = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.selectMe);
            cardView = (CardView) vi.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            this.context = context;

            vi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });

            vi.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                    return false;
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, final View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            menu.setHeaderIcon(appIcon.getDrawable());
            menu.setHeaderTitle(appName.getText());
            menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "WhatsApp").setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Post to whatsapp", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```